# How to exclude a day of the week with getDate in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

We are currently using the following script to close/open our store at certain times and it is working just fine:

```
<script>
  
  var Now = new Date(),
  CurrentDay = Now.getDay(),
  OpeningTimeMorning = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 13, 00),
  ClosingTimeMorning = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 16, 30),

  OpeningTimeEvening = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 19, 30),
  ClosingTimeEvening = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 23, 00),    

  OpenOnMorning = (Now.getTime() > OpeningTimeMorning.getTime() && Now.getTime() < ClosingTimeMorning.getTime());
  OpenOnEvening = (Now.getTime() > OpeningTimeEvening.getTime() && Now.getTime() < ClosingTimeEvening.getTime());

  if (!OpenOnMorning && !OpenOnEvening) {
      $('.instructions').toggle();
      $('.tt-shopcart-col').toggle();
      $('.tt-shopcart-table-02').toggle();
      $('.closed').toggle();
  }

</script>
```

But now we need it to stay closed on Mondays as well. What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? Like adding a check if `CurrentDay` is a "Monday", ...?

Comment: Hi Andreas, We were trying to modify the date via getDate, but obviously that was not the way to go. I'm no JavaScript expert. I'm also not looking to be given a straightforward solution, just to be pointed in the right direction. The code was written by someone I can't locate and we are trying to improve it as best we can. Thank you very much for your tip and have a nice day.

Comment: Is this code being run "on the server" or "by the client"? If the latter, then it's not a great idea to rely on the client clock being correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add IsMonday check

```
IsMonday = Now.getDay() === 1
if ((!OpenOnMorning && !OpenOnEvening) || IsMonday)
...
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much! It seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

The final code, thanks to [depperm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3462319/depperm) and [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas):

```
<script>
  
  var Now = new Date(),
  CurrentDay = Now.getDay(),
  IsMonday = Now.getDay() === 1
  OpeningTimeMorning = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 13, 00),
  ClosingTimeMorning = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 16, 30),

  OpeningTimeEvening = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 19, 30),
  ClosingTimeEvening = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 23, 00),    

  OpenOnMorning = (Now.getTime() > OpeningTimeMorning.getTime() && Now.getTime() < ClosingTimeMorning.getTime());
  OpenOnEvening = (Now.getTime() > OpeningTimeEvening.getTime() && Now.getTime() < ClosingTimeEvening.getTime());

  if ((!OpenOnMorning && !OpenOnEvening) || IsMonday) {
      $('.instructions').toggle();
      $('.tt-shopcart-col').toggle();
      $('.tt-shopcart-table-02').toggle();
      $('.closed').toggle();
  }

</script>
```